# 406 : "not applicable" when trying to stream DEX offers

Tags: stellar-sdk

I am trying to stream my dex offers, but I keep getting 406 : not applicable

To Reproduce

```js
// "stellar-sdk": "^5.0.2",
let StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk')
let server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon.stellar.org');

server.offers()
    .forAccount("GBNEOJ5TZEDXEE2IYKXQ2HQEIZUQGVLS74KNZ72MAWMNPA4IKFC7BHR7")
    .stream({
        onmessage: (currentOffers) => {
            console.log(currentOffers);
        },
        onerror: (err) => {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
```